# PHP sort array with names: 1.1.10 after 1.1.2

Tags: php, sorting, numbers

I have an array with file names and need to sort them based on their name.
Using the sort function it sorts as the example below. Now I need to have 1.1.10 to be sorted at then of the 1.1.x series. How can I achieve this?

array(14) {

[0]=>
  string(13) "1.1.1 Test111.xml"

[1]=>
  string(30) "1.1.10 Test1110.xml"

[2]=>
  string(28) "1.1.2 Test112.xml"

[3]=>
  string(21) "1.1.3 Test113.xml"

[4]=>
  string(17) "1.1.4 Test114.xml"

[5]=>
  string(29) "1.1.5 Test115.xml"

......

[10]=>
  string(16) "1.2.1 Test121.xml"

[11]=>
  string(24) "1.2.2 Test122.xml"

[12]=>
  string(23) "1.2.3 Test123.xml"

[13]=>
  string(17) "1.2.4 Test124.xml"
}

Comment: Hint: Before asking how to achieve something, perhaps first ask for the name? I think it's called "natural sort" and you know what, can you imagine you're not the first one asking this?